# Add header with username into request to backend in wso2 apimanager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have apimanger v1.5.0. It authorize request by access_token and forward to backend.
Backend need enduser name for processing request. I do not want add JWT-headers to request because that insecure.

Apimanager can add optional headers to request, if add to file `repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--common_v1.0.1.xml` in section `<outSequence><header>` some data for example `uri.var.accessToken`. But I dont know name of variable with enduser name.
Does somebody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable name is END_USER_NAME.

Example of use:

```
<inSequence>
        <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
        <property name="X-Test-Username" scope="transport" expression="get-property('END_USER_NAME')"></property>
        <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
```

And result in http headers:

```
GET http://backend.server:8080/sm/api/v1/common/user/example?access_token=4d758b64d5de15029c467dcd6feb354& HTTP/1.1
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Username: rudesu@example.com
Referer: https://example.com/src-jssip-osdk-test/
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
```

**THIS METHOD DOESN`T WORK IN APIM 1.7.0**

In 1.7.0 work:
`<property name="X-Test-Username" scope="transport" expression="get-property('END_USER_NAME')"/>`

Comment: Clarification: how does "X-Test-Username" keywork on top reflect to the resulting HTTP header below? Has that hardcoded-ly gone into "Username"? In other words, is "Username" configurable as a field name in resulting HTTP header?