# How to set tenant to header in mediator with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have an API that requires the tenant as a header.

If I create a custom in-sequence:

```
<sequence name="WSO2AM--Ext--In">
    <header
       name="X-Tenant-Id"
       scope="transport"
       action="set"
       expression="???????????????????"
    />
</sequence>
```

Is there an expression that I can use to achieve this? Or should I resort to creating a per-API mediator to set it?

PS:
Looking at WSO2 source code ([CarbonTenantInfoConfigurator.java](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/mediation-initializer/org.wso2.carbon.mediation.initializer/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/mediation/initializer/handler/CarbonTenantInfoConfigurator.java)), I found this fragment that could be useful as a hint:

```
PrivilegedCarbonContext cc = PrivilegedCarbonContext.getThreadLocalCarbonContext();
String tenantDomain = cc.getTenantDomain();
int tenantId = cc.getTenantId();
messageContext.setProperty("tenant.info.domain", tenantDomain);
messageContext.setProperty("tenant.info.id", tenantId);
```

But I don't know how to access to those properties in the custom sequence, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After checking the debug output from ApiManager, I noticed that custom sequences are being executed right after handlers. Luckily, the OAuthAuthenticator class (used by APIAuthenticationHandler) sets some handy properties like `END_USER_NAME` and `APPLICATION_NAME`.

`END_USER_NAME` contains the name and tenant of the caller (user@tenant.com).

This custom sequence worked for me:

```xml
<sequence name="add_service_header" trace="enable" statistics="enable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log/>
    <property name="tenant" expression="fn:substring-after(get-property('END_USER_NAME'), '@')" />
    <header name="X-Tenant" scope="transport" expression="get-property('tenant')"/>
    <header name="X-AppName" scope="transport" expression="get-property('APPLICATION_NAME')"/>
</sequence>
```

I could not find documentation for the property other than source code and [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23755852/add-header-with-username-into-request-to-backend-in-wso2-apimanager)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for and it works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the code suggests these are set to synapse MessageContext. You can retrieve these properties using following expressions.

get-property('tenant.info.domain')

get-property('tenant.info.id')

Thanks

Tishan

Comment: I tried that. Also tried `get-property(tenant.info.domain)`, `$ctx:tenant.info.domain` and `$axis2:tenant.info.domain` without success.

Comment: I tried with with ESB 4.8.0 and it is working as expected. Below is the synapse config segment used to set HTTP header.
<header name="X-Tenant"
  scope="transport"
  expression="get-property('tenant.info.domain')"/>